# SQL to split Comma Separated values and compare it with a multi list value in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a field in my table which has multiple reason codes concatenated in 1 column.
e.g. 2 records

```
Reason_Codes

Record1: 001,002,004,009,010

Record2: 001,003,005,006
```

In my SSRS report the user will be searching for data using one of the above reason codes. e.g.

- 001 will retrieve both records.
- 005 will retrieve the second record
  and so on.

Kindly advise how this can be achieved using SQL or Stored Procedure.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just passing in a single Reason Code to search on, you don't even need to bother with splitting the comma-separated list: you can just use a `LIKE` clause as follows:

```sql
SELECT tb.field1, tb.field2
FROM   SchemaName.TableName tb
WHERE  ',' + tb.Reason_Codes + ',' LIKE '%,' + @ReasonCode + ',%';
```

Try the following to see:

```sql
DECLARE @Bob TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, ReasonCodes VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @Bob (ReasonCodes) VALUES ('001,002,004,009,010');
INSERT INTO @Bob (ReasonCodes) VALUES ('001,003,005,006');

DECLARE @ReasonCode VARCHAR(5);


SET @ReasonCode = '001';

SELECT tb.ID, tb.ReasonCodes
FROM   @Bob tb
WHERE  ',' + tb.ReasonCodes + ',' LIKE '%,' + @ReasonCode + ',%';
-- returns both rows


SET @ReasonCode = '005';

SELECT tb.ID, tb.ReasonCodes
FROM   @Bob tb
WHERE  ',' + tb.ReasonCodes + ',' LIKE '%,' + @ReasonCode + ',%';
-- returns only row #2
```

Comment: Why concatenate the commas as well? Shouldn't just concatenating the % wildcard on either side of @Reasoncode be enough?

Comment: @Oliver It is to ensure that the string you are searching on isn't somehow a substring of a larger item in the delimited set. In this particular case, if all items are _always_ 3 digits then it might be ok to leave off the commas. But I just prefer to guarantee no false-positives by including the delimiter on both sides of the search string (and hence the need to also add them to the `ReasonCodes` column). In typical scenarios, someone is usually looking for `13` within `5,13,200,513,2135`, and it should only be the `13` that matches and not the `513` nor the `2135` items.

Comment: Srutzky, thanks a lot for helping to resolve this easily. I previously tried as Oliver suggested but missed your trick. great help. Thanks to Oliver and Naveed for your contributions towards my query

Answer (score 0):

I have blogged about something like this a long time ago. May be this will help: http://dotnetinternal.blogspot.com/2013/10/comma-separated-to-temp-table.html

The core solution would be to convert the comma separated values into a temporary table and then do a simple query on the temporary table to get your desired result.

Comment: Please do _not_ use a WHILE-based string splitter. That is one of the slowest methods. Please use either an Inline Table-Valued Function that itself uses an inline tally (or "numbers") table, OR use a SQLCLR splitter. Please see this article and the "discussion" forum linked to it [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). There is a SQLCLR splitter somewhere in that article or its forum, or you can also get one from the free [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com/) library (which I am the author of).

Comment: Naveed thanks for your suggestions. I would like to use Srutzky's answer as it sounds much easier